# sending JSON object from npm module to browser

Tags: node.js, npm, blockchain

How can I send the JSON object "data" returned by the npm module "blockchain.info" in the callback "onRequest". I want to write this data in the browser.

```
var http = require("http");
var blockchain = require('blockchain.info');
var blockexplorer = blockchain.blockexplorer;

var txAdress = 'b4b69abc03e4a801201e57ca57891002e5e756e85dde77a17deff0b107185a78';

blockexplorer.getTx(txAdress, function (err, data) {
   if (err) return console.error(err);
    console.log(data.size);  // works fine
});

var server = http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);

function onRequest(request, response) {
   response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
   response.write('<h3>List of transactions</h3>');
   //response.write('<p>' + data.size + '</p>');  // data undefined!
   response.end();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`data` doesn't exist in the scope of `onRequest`. [Learn about variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500431/218196).

`getTx` also appears to be an asynchronous function, you cannot simply "return" it from the callback (in case you wanted to try that). Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron) to learn about that.

A simple solution would be to make the call in the request event handler:

```
function onRequest(request, response) {

    blockexplorer.getTx(txAdress, function (err, data) {
       if (err) return console.error(err);
       response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
       response.write('<h3>List of transactions</h3>');
       response.write('<p>' + data.size + '</p>');
       response.end();
    });

}
```

Of course you have to poperly handle the error case as well and might want to cache the response from `getTx`.